# Prevent under-voltage warnings from printing to the console

Tags: power, terminal, logfiles

My Pi occasionally experiences an undervoltage for a second. I am working on fixing it but my main concern is that my Pi is being used in a kiosk application that displays a text output to the terminal screen (no GUI) using curses.

The message `Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)` is printed directly to the console, ruining my beautiful text based ASCII art kiosk display.

I've already added `avoid_warnings=1` to `boot/config.txt` and although that seems to hide the lightning-bolt and thermometer icons from the screen, the text messages still get printed to `stdout`.

This is a brand new behavior after upgrading the system:

```
Linux <name> 4.19.66-v7+ #1253 SMP Thu Aug 15 11:49:46 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Is there any other setting that will keep the errors quiet?

***Please don't educate me on power supplies and cables and voltage detection and measurement. This question is not about power. It is about disruptive error logging to the terminal.***

Comment: I think this may have solved my issue! https://askubuntu.com/questions/97256/how-do-i-disable-messages-or-logging-from-printing-on-the-console-virtual-termin `sudo dmesg -n 1`

Comment: This is a very bad idea.